# Array of Colors

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to work with an array of colors that is a constant. But Delphi keeps giving me compiling errors. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

```
const
  Statuses : array[0..3] of TAlphaColors =
                            (
                              TAlphaColors.Lightgray, //error here: says insert a '(', even though I already have one
                              TAlphaColors.Yellow,
                              TAlphaColors.Limegreen,
                              TAlphaColors.Blue
                             );
```

Comment: Use `array[0..3] of TAlphaColor`.

Comment: @TLama You could do that. But then you'd have something different. An array of `Cardinal` instead of an array of `TAlphaColors`. And if you want an array of `TAlphaColors` because you wish to pass its members to functions that expect `TAlphaColors` arguments, then you would need to make an extra step. Wrapping them all with `TAlphaColors.Create(Statuses[i])` doesn't seem like a lot of fun. Especially as it is simple enough to make an array of `TAlphaColors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you face is that `TAlphaColor.Lightgray`, and indeed all the other `TAlphaColor.XXX` that you name are ordinal true constant. Whereas `TAlphaColors` is a record type.

Let's take a look at the relevant definitions:

```
type
  TAlphaColor = type Cardinal;

  TAlphaColorRec = record
  const
    Alpha = TAlphaColor($FF000000);
    Aliceblue = Alpha or TAlphaColor($F0F8FF);
    Antiquewhite = Alpha or TAlphaColor($FAEBD7);
    .... many more color constant omitted
    constructor Create(const Color: TAlphaColor);
    class var ColorToRGB: function (Color: TAlphaColor): Longint;
    case LongWord of
      0:
        (Color: TAlphaColor);
      2:
        (HiWord, LoWord: Word);
      3:
{$IFDEF BIGENDIAN}
        (A, R, G, B: System.Byte);
{$ELSE}
        (B, G, R, A: System.Byte);
{$ENDIF}
  end;
```

So the constants are not of type `TAlphaColorRec`. Indeed it's one of the great frustrations of the language that you cannot declare nested constants  in a record that are of that record type. These constants are ordinal true constants.

Note that the record itself has data in a variant part of the record. And the field of interest is the `Color` field. So, you could declare your constant array like so:

```
const
  Statuses : array[0..3] of TAlphaColors = (
    (Color: TAlphaColors.Lightgray),
    (Color: TAlphaColors.Yellow),
    (Color: TAlphaColors.Limegreen),
    (Color: TAlphaColors.Blue)
  );
```

If only Embarcadero had had the foresight to allow us to write code like this:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
  public
    const
      MyConst: TMyRecord = ();
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info and clarification!